# How do I get an Option<T> instead of an Option<Vec<T>> from a Diesel query which only returns 1 or 0 records?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm querying for existing records in a table called `messages`; this query is then used as part of a 'find or create' function:

```
fn find_msg_by_uuid<'a>(conn: &PgConnection, msg_uuid: &Uuid) -> Option<Vec<Message>> {
    use schema::messages::dsl::*;
    use diesel::OptionalExtension;

    messages.filter(uuid.eq(msg_uuid))
        .limit(1)
        .load::<Message>(conn)
        .optional().unwrap()
}
```

I've made this optional as both finding a record and finding none are both valid outcomes in this scenario, so as a result this query might return a `Vec` with one `Message` or an empty `Vec`, so I always end up checking if the `Vec` is empty or not using code like this:

```
let extant_messages = find_msg_by_uuid(conn, message_uuid);

if !extant_messages.unwrap().is_empty() { ... }
```

and then if it isnt empty taking the first `Message` in the `Vec` as my found message using code like

```
let found_message = find_msg_by_uuid(conn, message_uuid).unwrap()[0];
```

I always take the first element in the `Vec` since the records are unique so the query will only ever return 1 or 0 records.

This feels kind of messy to me and seems to take too many steps, I feel as if there is a record for the query then it should return `Option<Message>` not `Option<Vec<Message>>` or `None` if there is no record matching the query.

Comment: you probably want to use [first](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/prelude/trait.FirstDsl.html#method.first)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use [`first`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/prelude/trait.FirstDsl.html#method.first):

> Attempts to load a single record. Returns `Ok(record)` if found, and `Err(NotFound)` if no results are returned. If the query truly is optional, you can call `.optional()` on the result of this to get a `Result<Option<U>>`.

```
fn find_msg_by_uuid<'a>(conn: &PgConnection, msg_uuid: &Uuid) -> Option<Message> {
    use schema::messages::dsl::*;
    use diesel::OptionalExtension;

    messages
        .filter(uuid.eq(msg_uuid))
        .first(conn)
        .optional()
        .unwrap()
}
```