# Is there a process through which I can figure out the correct types for my Diesel functions?

Tags: types, rust, rust-diesel

I'm using Diesel and would like to pass parts of my queries into functions and return parts of queries from functions. I'm struggling with working out my function signatures.

I want to load a blog post by ID, but first I want to filter it:

```
let query = wp_posts
    .filter(post_type.eq("solution_article"))
    .filter(post_status.eq("publish"))
    .limit(1);
```

Then I'm going to pass it over to another function to load by ID

```
pub fn query_by_id<Q>(db: &PooledMySqlConnection, query: Q, id: u64) -> Option<Post>
where
    Q: QueryDsl,
{
    let result = query.filter(ID.eq(id)).load::<Post>(db);
    if let Ok(mut result) = result {
        return result.pop();
    }
    None
}
```

This doesn't work because I'm struggling to find the correct type for `Q`. The compiler, unusually, isn't much help (or I don't understand it):

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<Q as diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<_>>::Output`
  --> src/endpoint.rs:37:10
   |
37 |         .filter(ID.eq(id))
   |          ^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="2048"]` attribute to your crate
```

I've raised the recursion limit multiple times to no avail.

Similarly, I would like to return my common filters from a function, so I need to find this type too.

While I'm sure someone could just tell me the correct types to use, how can I step through and find this myself? I was sure [`QueryDsl`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html) would be the right type from the documentation, where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are the types/definitions of `post_type` and `post_status`?

Comment: They're columns coming from diesels schema code gen: `use schema::wp_posts::dsl::*` both are a diesel `Varchar` type (afaik)

Comment: Have you read http://diesel.rs/guides/composing-applications/ ?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel-specific MCVE tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) as well.

Comment: If you are looking for a process, please review [How do I combine multiple functions using Diesel into one through abstraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47874398/155423). Does that answer your question?