# How to access concrete columns of a table accessed generically in Diesel?

Tags: generics, rust, rust-diesel

I'm having difficulty selecting an accurate and concise title for this question.

This question expands on the excellent answer given by @Shepmaster here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880065/3224771

The solution of which is:

```rust
use diesel::expression::operators::Desc;
use diesel::helper_types::{Limit, Order};
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{LimitDsl, OrderDsl};
use diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery;

pub fn get_most_recent_entry<'a, Tbl, Expr, Record>(
    conn: &SqliteConnection,
    table: Tbl,
    time: Expr,
) -> Result<i32, String>
where
    Expr: diesel::ExpressionMethods,
    Tbl: OrderDsl<Desc<Expr>>,
    Order<Tbl, Desc<Expr>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record> + LimitDsl,
    Limit<Order<Tbl, Desc<Expr>>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record>,
    Record: Time,
{
    table
        .order(time.desc())
        .first(conn)
        .optional()
        .map(|x| x.map_or(0, |x| x.time()))
        .map_err(|e| format!("Error here! {:?}", e))
}
```

In the snippet above, the `Table` and `Expression` are being provided as arguments. How could this function be further abstracted such that both the `Table` and `Expression` do not have to be passed as parameters?

I've figured out how to abstract the `Table` (see below), but I can't figure out how to remove the `Expression` argument so that the function can be used with any `Table` that contains the `time` column.

```rust
use diesel::expression::operators::Desc;
use diesel::helper_types::{Limit, Order};
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{LimitDsl, OrderDsl};
use diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery;
use diesel::SqliteConnection;
use crate::diesel::{RunQueryDsl, OptionalExtension};
use diesel::associations::HasTable;

pub trait Time {
    fn time(&self) -> i32;
}

pub fn get_most_recent_entry<'a, Tbl, Expr, Record>(
    conn: &SqliteConnection,
    time: Expr,
) -> Result<i32, String>
where
    Expr: diesel::ExpressionMethods,
    Tbl: HasTable,
    Tbl::Table: OrderDsl<Desc<Expr>>,
    Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<Expr>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record> + LimitDsl,
    Limit<Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<Expr>>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record>,
    Record: Time,
{
    Tbl::table()
        .order(time.desc())
        .first(conn)
        .optional()
        .map(|x| x.map_or(0, |x| x.time()))
        .map_err(|e| format!("Error here! {:?}", e))
}
```

**UPDATED**

Something like this:

```
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["sqlite", "extras"] }
```

```rust
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Cat {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    time: i32 //time record created
}

impl Time for Cat {
    fn time(&self) -> i32 {
        self.time
    }
}

pub fn get_most_recent_entry<'a, Tbl, Record>(
    conn: &SqliteConnection
) -> Result<i32, String>
where 
    // Don't know how to setup trait bounds for the expression
    // to express any table that has the same time column
{
    Tbl::table()
        .order(Tbl::columns::time.desc()) // Something like this
        .first(conn)
        .optional()
        .map(|x| x.map_or(0, |x| x.time()))
        .map_err(|e| format!("Error here! {:?}", e))
}

use crate::schema::cat;
fn main() {
    let conn = pool.get()?;
    get_most_recent_entry::<cat::dsl::cat, _>(&conn)
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to answer the question as it is. Please add the necessary context. This includes at least the concrete versions for diesel and rust are using, an exemplary call to that function and especially more details about what should be allowed as time expression and what not. As the code is currently written it accepts arbitrary expressions there which you cannot just construct inside the function without loosing functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to access columns in such a generic way. Each column is it's own zero sized struct placed in a module named after the table. (See the ["Schema in depth" guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/schema-in-depth.html) for details about the code generated by `table!`). Rust does not offer any option to address different types from the same module through generics.

That written it is possible to just provide your own trait that allows you to specify the corresponding column and implement it for the corresponding table (or model, or whatever type you want):

```rust
trait MyTimeColumnHelper {
    type TimeColumn: Default;
}


impl MyTimeColumnHelper for crate::schema::cat::table {
     type TimeColumn = crate::schema::cat::time;
}
```

So that your generic function can have a bound to this additional trait:

```rust
pub fn get_most_recent_entry<'a, Tbl, Record>(
    conn: &SqliteConnection
) -> Result<i32, String>
where 
    MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn: diesel::ExpressionMethods,
    Tbl: HasTable + MyTimeColumnHelper,
    Tbl::Table: OrderDsl<Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>,
    Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record> + LimitDsl,
    Limit<Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record>,
    Record: Time,
    Tbl::Table: OrderDsl<Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>,
    Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record> + LimitDsl,
    Limit<Order<Tbl::Table, Desc<MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn>>>: LoadQuery<SqliteConnection, Record>,
    Record: Time,
{
    Tbl::table()
        .order(MyTimeColumnHelper::TimeColumn::default().desc()) 
        .first(conn)
        .optional()
        .map(|x| x.map_or(0, |x| x.time()))
        .map_err(|e| format!("Error here! {:?}", e))
}
```